# SQLite Min function returns NULL in row with String data

Tags: sql, sqlite

Eventhough in every place I found it reads `MIN()` would only return `NULL` if a row is empty, for me it is different.
I have the following table:

```
+---+------------+------------+------------+
|   |  column1   |  column2   |  column3   |
+---+------------+------------+------------+
| 3 | 2016-11-01 | 2016-11-02 | 2016-10-27 |
| 4 | NULL       | NULL       | 2016-10-28 |
| 5 | 2013-12-12 | 2016-11-02 | 2016-10-30 |
+---+------------+------------+------------+
```

And try to get the smallest value of each row using

```
SELECT MIN(column1, column2, column3) FROM myTable
```

to compare it using

```
WHERE STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d', MIN(column1, column2, column3)) BETWEEN DATE('2000-01-01') and DATE('2016-11-10');
```

However the first line returns the following output:

```
+-------------------------------+
| MIN(column1, column2, column3 |
+-------------------------------+
| 2016-10-27                    |
| NULL                          |
| 2013-12-12                    |
+-------------------------------+
```

And resulting the `WHERE` statement will not include the row.

What I was hoping for:

```
+-------------------------------+
| MIN(column1, column2, column3 |
+-------------------------------+
| 2016-10-27                    |
| 2016-10-28                    |
| 2013-12-12                    |
+-------------------------------+
```

How could I change the statement to not include `NULL` cells or change the table to work properly?

EDIT: There will NEVER be a totally empty row! This table is connected to a Java application that will take care of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer isn't nice, and I suspect there might be a better way.  But one option would be to use `IFNULL` on each date column and replace with a really high date value in the case that the value be `NULL`:

```
SELECT MIN(IFNULL(column1, '9999-01-01'),
           IFNULL(column2, '9999-01-01'),
           IFNULL(column3, '9999-01-01'))
FROM myTable
WHERE STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d', MIN(IFNULL(column1, '9999-01-01'),
                               IFNULL(column2, '9999-01-01'),
                               IFNULL(column3, '9999-01-01')))
      BETWEEN DATE('2000-01-01') AND DATE('2016-11-10');
```

Comment: This works great! This could actually solve my problem... I could set the default value to this high date and create rows with that value. You said it; it is not very clean, but unless there is no other solution I will take that! Thanks already. However I will wait a bit and see if there will be other answers :)

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Yes, please wait a while.  Also note that my solution is not so nice if all three values are missing.  In this case, you would get `9999-01-01` as the minimum date, which is wrong (it should be `NULL`).  You could wrap the entire call to `MIN` in a `CASE` expression which checks for `9999-01-01`, but now this would really be getting ugly.

Comment: There will never be a totally empty row. I forgot to mention that in the question. There will be a Java application taking care of that.